# Iterate over STI list in rails 4

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4, sti

I have two sub models, called: `Service` and `Product` that inherits from `ProductBase`. And I have another model to consume it. `Acquire` that have many `AcquireBasket`. Check out my code:

product_base.rb:

```
  class ProductBase < ActiveRecord::Base
    extend ::EnumerateIt
    include Searchable

    self.table_name = 'products'
  end
```

product.rb:

```
  class Product < ProductBase
    default_scope { where(kind: ProductKind::PRODUCT) }

    def initialize(attributes = {})
      super(attributes)
      self.kind   = ProductKind::PRODUCT
      self.status = ProductStatus::DRAFT
    end
  end
```

service.rb:

```
  class Service < ProductBase
    default_scope { where(kind: ProductKind::SERVICE) }

    def initialize(attributes = {})
      super(attributes)
      self.kind   = ProductKind::SERVICE
      self.status = ProductStatus::DRAFT
    end
  end
```

acquire_basket.rb:

```
 class AcquireBasket < ActiveRecord::Base
    extend ::EnumerateIt

    belongs_to :acquire
    belongs_to :product
 end
```

In some part of my project, I get a list (acquire baskets) of both models, `Service` and `Product`. And I need to check if I have services inside of it.

My code to check was:

```
def services_in?(acquire)
  acquire.baskets.map(&:product).detect(&:service?)
end
```

The code works, ONLY if I pass services first, and products after!! Or if I have only one of them.

Answer (score 1):

You should be able to utilize the `descendents` method to iterate over all of the subclasses

Answer (score 0):

I can't find the answer in blog post around the world, so I will share with you:

```
 class AcquireBasket < ActiveRecord::Base
   extend ::EnumerateIt

   belongs_to :acquire
   belongs_to :product, class_name: 'ProductBase'
 end
```

The problem was, when I try to find (lazily) in a ActiveRecord::Relation, Rails lookup (I think) to just `Product` model. And It can't find other type models inside of it. So using this typo I put it to work.